# Getting internal server errors from webconfig URL redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

Not sure why this is happening, but whether I have `%20` or  it seems to cause the application to completely break. I have a url that I want to redirect using some query parameters, like so:

`enroll.html --> /connect/sign-up.aspx?utm_source=Prospect%20Brochure%20and%20Quizk%20Guide&utm_medium=Print&utm_content=alprolixdotcomslashdiscover&utm_campaign=Vanity%20URL`

Here's my rule:

```
        <rule name="ALP Prospect Brochure And ALP Quick Guide" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
             <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/enroll.html" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="/connect/sign-up.aspx?utm_source=Prospect Brochure and Quizk Guide&utm_medium=Print&utm_content=alprolixdotcomslashdiscover&utm_campaign=Vanity URL" redirectType="Permanent"/>
        </rule>
```

Can't seem to find any documentation that states explicitly what is allowed in an action url redirect, I'm assuming it's because of the `%20` or , how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was using `&` instead of `&amp;`